# python amara bindery and py2exere

Tags: xpath

I want to read xml and treat that as python data structure.
I am using amara bindery tools to do this. 
I use bindery.parse to read the xml and that returns the xml in the format of the data structures I want. This works fine on the interpreter. I am then using py2exe to convert my script into a windows executable. 
When I run the executable I get the following error:

```
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "amara\bindery\__init__.pyo", line 38, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "amara\bindery\nodes.pyo", line 27, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "amara\xpath\__init__.pyo", line 99, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 82, in load_module
File "amara\xpath\parser\__init__.pyo", line 2, in <module>
File "zipextimporter.pyo", line 98, in load_module
ImportError: No module named predicates
```

Can anyone suggest the reason for these and what could be the issues?

Thanks in advance.